# How to minimize a news like app size under 10 MB with audioplayer added in it using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to create an news app using dart with other activities included such as images,quiz system, audio player to read out the content, login-sign up activity , online-offline mode, battery saver mode .
Just after installing flutter package it builds an app of size if 50 MB with just a push button. 
More over i wanted to know can i develop this app without using android studio as Visual studio code provides flutter package.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. How did you take your output? Is it APK? Which commands did you use? Also [Flutter's official Discord channel](https://discord.gg/hTfdgf) is more suitable to get suggestions.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that you're not going to get a small APK using flutter. Tiny APKs can really only be achieved using a native approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to build `App bundle` instead of `APK`, such that it would reduce app size, because as per my knowledge your app also contains flutter engine which is around 7MB , correct me if I'm wrong. 
**Yes** you can use `Visual Studio Code` to develop flutter apps instead of `android studio`.